# C++11 search an std::map with composite key

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I want to implement a function (findn) below that search on the std::map to find an element. However in my case the key is composite value, it is an `<int,int>`

How do I use the `std::map.find` here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string> studentMap;

int insert(int i, int j, std::string name) {
        if( !studentMap.insert( std::make_pair ( std::make_pair(i,j), name)).second ) { 
                std::cout << "game not added" << std::endl;
        } else {
                std::cout << "game added" << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}

void findn(int i, int j) {
// how to find when we have composite key?
}

int main() {
        insert(1,1,"test");
        insert(1,1,"tes");
        insert(1,2,"test 2");

        std::cout << studentMap.size() << std::endl;
        findn(1,1);
}
```

Comment: If the key *wasn't* a `std::pair`, how would you do it then? What makes you think it would be that different in this case?

Comment: I just asked if the normal find methods works for composite keys.

Comment: It would have been very simple to just try it first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the work:

```
auto it = mymap.find(std::make_pair(i,j));
```

Comment: How do I check that "it" exists?

Comment: `bool exists = it != mymap.end`; [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) returns end iterator if no element is found